# Design a data structure which can store customer details

Tags: algorithm

Interview question:

A store has n customers and any customer can visit them any time through out the year.Data is stored in a file.Design a data structure to find given person visited the store on given date or not.

I think Hashmap would be fine to implement the above requirement.

Can some one give me a better solution..Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If n and the range of dates is large then the file will be large and it may run slowly.  You may not be able to load it all into memory at one time - or it will be slow even if you can.  A 'better' approach probably means going faster and use less resources.  You could speed things up by having some sort of indexing into the file by date and only looking into the chunk of the file that is for the date in question.  This would significantly reduce the (usually slowest) part - getting the data from disk to memory - and then just need to use a hash of names within that chunk.